# Bash - Search and append strings

Tags: linux, bash

If I wanted to search for a line in a file and append a string to the end of that line, how can I go about it?  I.E.:

```
file=?
```

I want to search for `file=?` and replace the question mark with a file path. The file path is located in a variable `$FILEPATH`

```
file=$FILEPATH
```

Thanks!

EDIT

```
sed -i -f "s,file=\?,file=$FILEPATH,g"
```

The above works well and is what I'm looking for but is there a way to replace the question mark? With the code above if I have the following:

```
FILEPATH=/file/path
```

Properties file:

```
something=?
file=?
```

The replacement produces:

Properties file:

```
something=?
file=/file/path?
```

Is there a way to replace the `?` completely?

Comment: `-i` switch will edit files in place (and make backups if an extension is supplied) so you must supply a file name. `-f` is only needed when the `sed` commands are supplied via script. In this case you are supplying the commands on the command line so this switch is not needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use sed for that:

```
sed -i "s/file=?/file=$FILEPATH/g" your_file
```

If your `$FILEPATH` has `/` then use a different `sed` separator, something like:

```
sed -i "s,file=?,file=$FILEPATH,g"
```

Comment: If `$FILENAME` contains `/`, which a filename is fairly likely to, you'll need to escape them: `${FILENAME//\//\\\/}`

Comment: Good point, but in that case I'd use a different separator: `sed -i -f "s,file=\?,file=$FILEPATH,g"`

Comment: When I placed this in a script "sed -i -f filename "s/file=\?/file=$FILEPATH/g", I get this following error when i run it: "sed: file filename line 1: unknown command: `j'".

Comment: Sorry, I shouldn't have `-f` in there, although it looks as though you added 'filename' after the `-f`. Either use `-f` with a script file or place the script inline as I did. Post updated.

Comment: Apparently within parens it has to be `${TMP//\//\/}`

Comment: "sed -i -f "s,file=\?,file=$FILEPATH,g"" works well. Is there a way to replace the question mark? Right now I'm getting $FILEPATH+?

Comment: The `s` command takes in first the regexp to match and second the replacement text. So, as long as the question mark is being matched it  will be replaced. You could try adding `-r` to make it an extended regexp, but I'd expect `?` to be a part of the standard regexp.

Comment: Confirmed. The question mark does NOT need to be escaped. You can either add `-r` and leave it escaped or remove the backslash. Post updated.

Answer (score 1):

Don't escape your question mark

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat temp
file=?
file=?

[jaypal:~/Temp] echo $filepath
/usr/bin

[jaypal:~/Temp] sed -e 's_file=?_file='$filepath'_g' temp
file=/usr/bin
file=/usr/bin
```

Also to make inline changes I would recommend to use the following -

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] sed -ibak 's_file=?_file='$filepath'_g' temp

[jaypal:~/Temp] ls temp*
temp    tempbak

[jaypal:~/Temp] cat temp
file=/usr/bin
file=/usr/bin

[jaypal:~/Temp] cat tempbak
file=?
file=?
```

This will make a backup copy of your original file before making any changes. In case if anything goes wrong you will have your original copy protected.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Bash, you can simply use Bash builtins and substitutions instead of sed:

```
#!/bin/bash

FILEPATH="/file/path"

while read line; do
    echo "${line/file=\?/${line/\?/}$FILEPATH}"
done < yourfile
```